# Form Action Tag Helper in Razor Pages doesn't redirect me

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm trying to do a search box. When I press the search button nothing happens. I want to redirect to /Search&searchTerm=il. Also how to get what's typed in the input box and add it to the asp-route-searchTerm?

```html
<div class="input-group col-4">
  <input class="form-control py-2" type="search" placeholder="Search books and authors">
  <span class="input-group-append">
    <button asp-page="/Search" asp-route-searchTerm="il" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the other example is right as far as get, but rest is wrong tech
Razor Pages:

Html

```
<form sp-page="./Index" method="get">
                <div class="form-actions no-color">
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" name="SearchString" value="@Model.CurrentFilter" placeholder="Add search term" class="form-control" />
                        <button type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary btn-round">
                            <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                            Search
                        </button> |
                        <a asp-page="./Index">Back to full List</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Code Behind:

declare a holding property

```
public string CurrentFilter { get; set; }
```

Your OnGetAsync

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string searchString)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)) { CurrentFilter = searchString; }
```

Notice the form tag is:

notice that OnGet takes in a string ( query string param called searchString )

Notice that Text field has a name param.

The extra property CurrentFilter is so it can be remembered and model bound.   so paging, order by etc can also be in that URL

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, `form` tags in .NET Core has `method = "POST"` by default.

I see what you are trying to do is a GET request.

Try changing POST by GET.

```
<form method="GET">

</form>
```

And your button tag as follows:

```
<button asp-action="Search" asp-controller="YourController" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
```

Where, "Search" is the name of your action and "YourController" the name of your Controller.

and in **`YourController.cs`** on Search action:

```
public IActionResult Search(string SearchTerm)
{
    var model = new ModelClass();
    //Your search logic
    return View(model); 
}
```

Your search result page maybe named **`Search.cshtml`**, should receive a model of ModelClass like (this goes in the top of Search.cshtml):

```
@model YourProject.Models.ModelClass
```

Maybe your model should have properties like:

```
public class ModelClass
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    //more properties
}
```

Also, I don't want to sound rude but maube you should take a quick look again at MVC pattern design.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but actually i'm not talking about ASP.NET MVC, I'm talking for Razer Pages which uses MVVM pattern design and its' new in asp.net. Also provided html is in _Layout.cshtml and it doesn't have <form> tag. When using button tag helper instead of raw button html tag, razor generate formaction button.